# Python -- matplotlib elliptic curves

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, elliptic-curve, finite-field

I'm teaching myself about matplotlib and Python and I'm having a difficult time plotting an equation for an elliptic curve.  I have the equation down but I'm not doing the `y^2`

This is as much trouble as I was able to get myself into so far:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axislines import SubplotZero
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *


def plotGraph():
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    ax = SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    for direction in ["xzero", "yzero"]:
        ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style("-|>")
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    a = 5; b = 25
    x = np.arange(-50.0, 50.0, 1.0)
    y = pow(x,3) + a*x + b

    xmin = -50; xmax = 50; ymin = -50; ymax = 50
    v = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
    ax.axis(v)

    ax.plot(x, pow(y,2))

    #grid()
    #ax.grid(color='r', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)

    show()


def main():
    plotGraph()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `axis()` is there because I was also trying to get a clearer-looking chart with grid lines, and I thought that `grid()` would also take care of that but apparently not. I was also going to try to make it interactive where you click on the points you want and it calculates, but looking over the docs there seems like a lot of interaction mouse options but I don't see mouse interaction that creates some event by clicking on a point on the chart (after the 3rd time reading it over I'm still missing it).

I'm just going from the [pyplot summary on matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html) but I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong here.  The plot of the elliptic curve is way off, not even close.

This is probably a beginner mistake so a junior programmer who takes a second to read this will probably see very quickly why I'm not getting the curve I want.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you're right, you're not doing `y^2`. To plot elliptic curve in matplotlib I used this code (tested in Python 3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    a = -1
    b = 1

    y, x = np.ogrid[-5:5:100j, -5:5:100j]
    plt.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), pow(y, 2) - pow(x, 3) - x * a - b, [0])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've got this plot:
[image]

Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes thanks that's the basics of what I was trying to get to. +1 and accepted. Not sure if you happen to know how to highlight/show a specific point(s) on the curve and get a line between them.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure either, but you can create another question with description of what you want.