# how to graphically show bitcoin public key on the curve?

Tags: python, public-key, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

From what i understand private is a point on the Elliptic curve and a public key is *`x,y`* co-ordinates on the curve therefore showing them on the graph should be easy to those who knows how to code.
The below code shows the graph using python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

x = [3, 1, 2, 5]
y = [5, 2, 4, 7]

plt.plot(x, y, 'r*')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])

for i, j in zip(x, y):
   plt.text(i, j+0.5, '({}, {})'.format(i, j))

plt.show()
```

I need to do the same but with Elliptic curve and `x,y` co-ordinates of public key.
My goal is to find the relationship between 2 public key with bitcoin addresses that share the 8 first characters, so it would be easy if i see them on a curve.

i have read Scalar multiplication [HERE](https://onyb.gitbook.io/secp256k1-python/scalar-multiplication-in-python)

can someone show me how to show public and private key on the curve using python?

The below code is a sample from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756043/python-matplotlib-elliptic-curves)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    a = -1
    b = 1

    y, x = np.ogrid[-5:5:100j, -5:5:100j]
    plt.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), pow(y, 2) - pow(x, 3) - x * a - b, [0])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am still learning python.

[image: the curve that i want to see 2 public keys on]

Comment: like the curve in this link [link](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/public-key)

Comment: The private key is *not* a point on the curve. Curves in cryptography are over finite fields, so their "graph" is not really meaningful and for example doesn't have any continuous segments.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you are right, a private key is a number from which we derive public key(x,y). thats what i want to on the curve above